# VideoFeed not working on MavicAir 2 with the latest windows SDK

Tags: c#, dji-sdk

It was working well with windows SDK 0.2.0, I was able the control the UAV and got the FPV. I realized a new version SDK is released and I tried it. I found that the latest SDK only support moving command, I couldn't get any video data from the UAV, even with the sample code provided by DJI. Can anyone tell me what to do for getting video feed back with this sdk?

Here is the git sample code:

```
public sealed partial class FPVPage : Page
{
    private DJIVideoParser.Parser videoParser;

    public FPVPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
        InitializeVideoFeedModule();
        await DJI.WindowsSDK.DJISDKManager.Instance.ComponentManager.GetCameraHandler(0, 0).SetCameraWorkModeAsync(new CameraWorkModeMsg { value = CameraWorkMode.SHOOT_PHOTO });
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        UninitializeVideoFeedModule();
    }


    private async void InitializeVideoFeedModule()
    {
        //Must in UI thread
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
        {
            //Raw data and decoded data listener
            if (videoParser == null)
            {
                videoParser = new DJIVideoParser.Parser();
                videoParser.Initialize(delegate (byte[] data)
                {
                    //Note: This function must be called because we need DJI Windows SDK to help us to parse frame data.
                    return DJISDKManager.Instance.VideoFeeder.ParseAssitantDecodingInfo(0, data);
                });
                //Set the swapChainPanel to display and set the decoded data callback.
                videoParser.SetSurfaceAndVideoCallback(0, 0, swapChainPanel, ReceiveDecodedData);
                DJISDKManager.Instance.VideoFeeder.GetPrimaryVideoFeed(0).VideoDataUpdated += OnVideoPush;
            }
            //get the camera type and observe the CameraTypeChanged event.
            DJISDKManager.Instance.ComponentManager.GetCameraHandler(0, 0).CameraTypeChanged += OnCameraTypeChanged;
            var type = await DJISDKManager.Instance.ComponentManager.GetCameraHandler(0, 0).GetCameraTypeAsync();
            OnCameraTypeChanged(this, type.value);
        });
    }


    private void UninitializeVideoFeedModule()
    {
        if (DJISDKManager.Instance.SDKRegistrationResultCode == SDKError.NO_ERROR)
        {
            videoParser.SetSurfaceAndVideoCallback(0, 0, null, null);
            DJISDKManager.Instance.VideoFeeder.GetPrimaryVideoFeed(0).VideoDataUpdated -= OnVideoPush;
        }
    }

    //raw data
    void OnVideoPush(VideoFeed sender, byte[] bytes)
    {
        videoParser.PushVideoData(0, 0, bytes, bytes.Length);
    }

    //Decode data. Do nothing here. This function would return a bytes array with image data in RGBA format.
    async void ReceiveDecodedData(byte[] data, int width, int height)
    {
    }

    //We need to set the camera type of the aircraft to the DJIVideoParser. After setting camera type, DJIVideoParser would correct the distortion of the video automatically.
    private void OnCameraTypeChanged(object sender, CameraTypeMsg? value)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            switch (value.Value.value)
            {
                case CameraType.MAVIC_2_ZOOM:
                    this.videoParser.SetCameraSensor(AircraftCameraType.Mavic2Zoom);
                    break;
                case CameraType.MAVIC_2_PRO:
                    this.videoParser.SetCameraSensor(AircraftCameraType.Mavic2Pro);
                    break;
                default:
                    this.videoParser.SetCameraSensor(AircraftCameraType.Others);
                    break;
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome, Could you provide any source code you're using so far?

Answer (score 0):

DJI tech team quickly upload a new version sdk (0.3.1), problem solved